# Retrofit return null in body() method in Android

Tags: android, tomcat, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

I can not find where the semantic error is in these lines of code:

```
PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO puntoGpsRecorridoDto = new PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO();
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setDescripcion(puntoGpsRecorrido.getDescripcion());
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setIdRecorrido(37);            
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setDemoraSeg(2);
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setPrecisionMts(10); 
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setEstado(puntoGpsRecorrido.getEstado());
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setFechaHora(puntoGpsRecorrido.getFechaHora());
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setIdDispositivo("943953977-OFICINA");
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setLatitud(puntoGpsRecorrido.getLatitud());
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setLongitud(puntoGpsRecorrido.getLongitud());
puntoGpsRecorridoDto.setPrecisionMts(puntoGpsRecorrido.getPrecisionMts());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer()).create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(Util.URL_WS).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
LocationService locationService = retrofit.create(LocationService.class);
Call<EstadoDTO> callEstadoDto = locationService.enviarPuntoGpsRecorrido(puntoGpsRecorridoDto);
Response<EstadoDTO> exec = callEstadoDto.execute();
estadoDto = exec.body(); // <<<------ body() return NULL
```

LocationService Interface for retrofit client:

```
public interface LocationService
{
    @POST("recorrido/sending")
    Call<EstadoDTO> enviarPuntoGpsRecorrido(@Body PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO puntoGpsRecorridoDto);
}
```

Connect to service ? ---> YES,

It works by another way? --> Yes, with SoapUI test,

Server ? ---> Apache tomcat + Mysql + Hibernate

PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO class:

```
public class PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO 
{
    private Integer idRecorrido;
    private String idDispositivo;
    private Double latitud;
    private Double longitud;
    private Boolean estado;
    private String descripcion;
    private Integer precisionMts;
    private Integer demoraSeg;
    private Date fechaHora;

    public PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO()
    {
    } 
}
```

PuntoGpsRecorrido class:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "PuntoGpsRecorrido")
public class PuntoGpsRecorrido
{
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private Integer idRecorrido;

    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, canBeNull = false)
    private Dispositivo dispositivo;
    @DatabaseField
    private Double latitud;
    @DatabaseField
    private Double longitud;
    @DatabaseField
    private Boolean estado;
    @DatabaseField
    private String descripcion;
    @DatabaseField
    private Integer precisionMts;
    @DatabaseField
    private Integer demoraSeg;
    @DatabaseField
    private Date fechaHora;

    public PuntoGpsRecorrido()
    {}
}
```

EstadoDTO Class:

```
public class EstadoDTO
{
    public static final String EXITO="001";
    public static final String ERROR="000";

    private String code;
    private String msg;
    private String extra;

    public EstadoDTO()
    {}

}
```

Error:

[image]

Test with SoapUI, It goes very well:

[image]

> What am I doing wrong ?  Please let me know if you for more
>   information need. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your httpstatus code in the response? I wonder it is not in range 200~300

Comment: Thanks Long Ranger, the httpstatus code is : 500 Internal server error.

Comment: body() function will return result only when the http status code is in the range of 200~300. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097680/when-i-use-retrofit2-0-with-post-reponse-is-successful-but-the-reponse-code/39097896#39097896

Comment: I understand, but because the server returns me 500 if all goes well?, anyway you know where I can see the details of that error in Apache Tomcat?

Comment: You should check the log folder in your apache home location. If there is any error and you have code for logging in your web application, the log file should be in there. Does the errorBody contains all the information you need?

Comment: Error body does not contain information that can help me, basically it is a copy of rawResponse.

Comment: OK, it must be server error. Check the log in your server to see the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution!

1. Detected Error: Wrong serialization Date data type in an attribute
   of the object PuntoGpsRecorridoDTO send POJO Web service.

   `Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer()).create()`;

Solution: Replace by:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer()).create();
```

Aqui las clases:

JsonDateDeserializer class:

```
public class JsonDateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String s = json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(s); //long l = Long.parseLong(s.substring(6, s.length() - 2));
        Date d = new Date(l);
        return d;
    }
}
```

JsonDateSerializer class:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer implements JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Date src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context)
    {
        long l = src.getTime();
        JsonElement json = new JsonPrimitive(l);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Happy programming...

Answer (score 0):

Use below code,it will handle all sorts of failures from server, you may have to upgarde to latest version of Retrofit.

Call callEstadoDto = locationService.enviarPuntoGpsRecorrido(puntoGpsRecorridoDto);

```
            callEstadoDto.enqueue(new Callback<EstadoDTO>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response<EstadoDTO> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                    hideLoader();
                    if(response.isSuccess()){

                      //do your thing

                    }else{

                        String error=response.errorBody().string();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable t) {


                    Log.e("error " , ""+t.toString());
                }
            });
```